# Make a changing "news-div" with animated scroll

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, animation

I have made a simple lay-out for a div I want on my website. The div handles the news about the page.

The div looks like this: http://jsfiddle.net/6baouaLt/

The thing is that I want to have multiple news content in the same div, for example every 5 seconds the current new will scroll down and vanish with lets say overflow: hidden and then another new appears from the top of the div scrolled down.

EDIT: I have made a basic picture of how it should be done: [image: Picture]

I hope you understand what I mean, Otherwise I can explain further more.

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8" />
    <title>News div</title>
    <style type="text/css">
        div.newswrap
            {
                width: 522px;

                box-shadow: 0 10px 5px #c9c9c9;

            }
        div.newstitle
            {
                background-color: #54B3F4;
                display: inline-block;
                margin-right: -4px;
                border-right: 1px solid black;
                padding: 5px 10px;


            }
        div.newscontent
            {
                display: inline-block;
                background-color: #f49554;
                padding: 5px 10px;
            }
        .newstitle > span
            {
                font-family: sans-serif;
                font-weight: 600;
                letter-spacing: 1px;
            }


    </style>
</head>
<body>
    <div class="newswrap">
        <div class="newstitle">
            <span>NEWS</span>
        </div>
        <div class="newscontent">
            <span class="newsspan">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Obcaecati</span>
        </div>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: To make life easier - find some slideshow plugin, with scroll animation, and make this in few minutes... I suggest: http://jquery.malsup.com/cycle/

Comment: I tried this and It works fine, now I just have to change the settings a bit, thank you!